# PHP class constructor setting all values as null

Tags: php

I have a class to register users in my web application, and the constructor does the basic validation and sanitization. The problem is, when I try and dump out the values, all of them are empty strings. Here is the code in the `RegisterUser` class:

```
<?php

class RegisterUser {

    public $firstName = ""; 
    public $lastName = ""; 
    public $email = ""; 
    public $password = "";

    // Validating registration data
    function _construct($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password) {
        $firstName = filter_var($firstName, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $lastName = filter_var($lastName, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $password = filter_var($password, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if (empty($firstName) || !preg_match("^[A-Za-z.\s_-]+$", $firstName)) {
            throw new Exception("First name not filled in or is invalid.");
        }
        if (empty($lastName) || !preg_match("^[A-Za-z.\s_-]+$", $lastName)) {
            throw new Exception("Last name not filled in or is invalid.");
        }
        if (empty($email) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            throw new Exception("Email not filled in or is invalid.");
        }
        if (empty($password) || !preg_match("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*]).{8,}", $password)) {
            throw new Exception("Password not filled in or is invalid.");
        }
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

}
```

And here is how I'm calling it in my `index.php` file:

```
$register = new RegisterUser($registerFormData["firstName"], $registerFormData["lastName"], $registerFormData["email"], $registerFormData["password"]);<br>
```

I have also done `var_dump($registerFormData)` and it has returned the correctly submitted values.

Here is the short version:
**Why, when I try to `var_dump($register)`, do I get all blank values?**

Comment: and there is no any error?

Comment: @MrSmile none at all

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but why should it not get blank since you are not returning anything

Comment: try doing this: var_dump($register->firstName); and see what it returns

Comment: @Penguine `string(0) ""`

Comment: That's because it's `__construct( )`, not `_construct( )`

Comment: exactly. there should be two underscores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must use **two** underscores with a constructor, like this:

```
function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password) {
```

more about constructor [here](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: That is what did it!! Thank you!! As soon as I can, I'll accept the answer!!